# Pass values between two actions with out passing them through url,in Zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-studio

Is there any specific way to pass values between two actions without passing them through urls in Zend?

```
<a href="#">View</a>
```

This is where I have to use it. When I click on view, I should be redirected to a different action on another controller, and there I have to get the values. Also, using session is not permitted in my case.

Comment: You cannot do it from the view without making a request to the server. To me it sounds like you want to make an AJAX request and then include your values in the POST data. Otherwise I am not entirely sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: hey,thanks andy
The thing is, I want to pass a value to another action without leaving any trace on the client side(something like Zend_Registry.But the problem wit the zend Registry is that it keeps its values for a single request). I'm familiar with ajax and I'm aware that we can see the parameters even if we use ajax POST.

Answer (score 1):

here in your case for passing value from phtm to another controller action you have to pass it either through get /post method.
like this 
`<a href="/yourcontroller/action/param_name/value">View</a>` and in your acion use `$this->getRequest()->getParam('param_name');`

```
below given may be helpful
```

after completing one action call another action use forward

```
`$this->_forward('controller','action2');`
```

then use

```
   $test=$this->getRequest()->getParam('yourparam');
```

or `keep in zend registry` if u have the value in bootstrap

`Zend_Registry::set('param ', value);`

Comment: Hey Arun,
Thanks for your reply. But in my case all the parameter values are generated dynamically from the '.phtml' inside a foreach loop. In such a case what can I do?

Comment: u have to muse either get, post, or session

Comment: wht are u doing ...<a href="/yourcontroller/action/param_name/value">View</a> and in your acion use $this->getRequest()->getParam('param_name');

Comment: The topic is "Pass values between two actions with out passing them through url". I appreciate your help. Thank you Arun.